# Multiple Overriding Methods for onClick()

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-studio

I am trying to wire a button to a text, which is basically the text changes whenever someone presses the button. I wrote 5 over-riding methods cont. named onClick(View v) inside the listener method. But when I build my app and open it on my device, only the last message prints, I know this is because the last overRiding methods mutes the others, but how can I print all the message one by one at each click to button.?

```
    Button new_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button);
    //now we gotta set up the event listener
    new_button.setOnClickListener(
            //here we will put call back method,
            //after someone click the button
            //this methods's body get's executed
            //this is interface
            new Button.OnClickListener(){
                public void onClick(View v){
                    TextView Text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Text);
                    Text.setText("YOU PRESSED IT!");
                }
            }
    );
    new_button.setOnClickListener(
            new Button.OnClickListener(){
                public void onClick(View v){
                    TextView Text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Text);
                    Text.setText("Please don't press it again :)");
                }
            }
    );
    new_button.setOnClickListener(
            new Button.OnClickListener(){
                public void onClick(View v){
                    TextView Text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Text);
                    Text.setText("You Pressed it again! >:{");
                }
            }
    );
    new_button.setOnClickListener(
            new Button.OnClickListener(){
                public void onClick(View v){
                    TextView Text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Text);
                    Text.setText("Stop Pressssssing It");
                }
            }
    );
    new_button.setOnClickListener(
            new Button.OnClickListener(){
                public void onClick(View v){
                    TextView Text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Text);
                    Text.setText("Please Stop It!");
                }
            }
    );
```

Comment: There is a Semantic difference between adding listener (when you could add a bunch of them on event) and setting listener (when you can only set one. Next listener will drop previous one).

Answer (score 0):

You can maintain the current state in a variable, and depending on the state set the proper text. Something like,

```
int currentState = 0;
TextView Text;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Button new_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button);

    Text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Text);

    //now we gotta set up the event listener
    new_button.setOnClickListener(
        //here we will put call back method,
        //after someone click the button
        //this methods's body get's executed
        //this is interface
        new Button.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                if (currentState == 0) {
                    Text.setText("YOU PRESSED IT!");
                    currentState++;
                } else if (currentState == 1) {
                    Text.setText("Please don't press it again :)");
                    currentState++;
                }
                ... and so on ...
            }
        }
    );
```

Answer (score -1):

Here you go! Don't forget to edit `YOUR_PROJECT` in the files below.

**Your Java file:**

```
package YOUR_PROJECT;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import static YOUR_PROJECT.R.*;

public class Test extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(layout.activity_test);
    Button new_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button);
    new_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        int i = 0;
        TextView Text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Text);
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            if (i == 0) {
                Text.setText("YOU PRESSED IT!");
                i++;
            } else {
                if (i == 1) {
                    Text.setText("Please don't press it again :)");
                    i++;
                } else {
                    if (i == 2) {
                        Text.setText("Please Stop It!");
                        i++;
                    } else {
                        if (i == 3) {
                            Text.setText("Stop Pressssssing It");
                            i++;
                        } else {
                            if (i == 4) {
                                Text.setText("You Pressed it again! >:{");
                            } else
                                i = 0;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        });
 }
}
```

**Your XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="YOUR_PROJECT.Test">

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button"
    android:id="@+id/Button"
    android:layout_marginTop="101dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/Text"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Button"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/Button"
    android:layout_marginTop="125dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```